# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:in colors.py

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a 3D LE (Laplacian Eigenmaps) with ideas from https://github.com/zjxi/Manifold-Learning-Algorithms
First I define a le() as follows:

```
def le(data_in, dim_out, k=15):
    data_len = len(data_in)
    weight = np.zeros([data_len, data_len], np.float)
    for i in range(data_len):
        knn_dots, distance_list = knn(data_in, i, k)
        # weight[i][knn_dots] = np.exp(-np.square(distance_list[knn_dots]) / (i + 1.))
        weight[i][knn_dots] = 1.0
    mat_d = np.diag(np.sum(weight, axis=0))
    mat_l = mat_d - weight
    val, vec = np.linalg.eig(mat_l)
    return np.reshape(vec[np.argsort(val)[:dim_out]], [data_len, dim_out])
```

Then I use LE to scatter the result:

```
def le_plot_3d(data, target):
    Z_LE = Le.le(data, 3)
    ax = Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter(Z_LE[:, 0], Z_LE[:, 1], Z_LE[:, 2], c=target, s=60)
    plt.title('LE')
    plt.show()
```

Then in the main method,I invoke the le_plot_3d(data, target) like :

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import datasets
import LaplacianEigenmap as Le
import LLE
import numpy as np

def knn(data_in, central_idx, k):
    central_dot, data_len = data_in[central_idx], len(data_in)
    distance_list = np.zeros([data_len], np.float)
    for i in range(data_len):
        distance_list[i] = np.linalg.norm(data_in[i] - central_dot)
    return np.argsort(distance_list)[:k], distance_list

def le(data_in, dim_out, k=15):
    data_len = len(data_in)
    weight = np.zeros([data_len, data_len], np.float)
    for i in range(data_len):
        knn_dots, distance_list = knn(data_in, i, k)
        # weight[i][knn_dots] = np.exp(-np.square(distance_list[knn_dots]) / (i + 1.))
        weight[i][knn_dots] = 1.0
    mat_d = np.diag(np.sum(weight, axis=0))
    mat_l = mat_d - weight
    val, vec = np.linalg.eig(mat_l)
    return np.reshape(vec[np.argsort(val)[:dim_out]], [data_len, dim_out])

def le_plot_3d(data, target):
    Z_LE = Le.le(data, 3)
    ax = Axes3D(plt.figure())
    ax.scatter(Z_LE[:, 0], Z_LE[:, 1], Z_LE[:, 2], c=target, s=60)
    plt.title('LE')
    plt.show()

def main():
    data, target = datasets.samples_generator.make_s_curve(1000, random_state=9)
    le_plot_3d(data, target)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the desired result:want to scatter the points I have generated by datasets.samples_generator.make_s_curve and use Laplacian Eigenmap to embed the points.
[image: LE-3d]

However I get:`ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: masked_array(data=[0.269944  +0.j, 0.014625  +0.j, 0.341379  +0.j, 0.47667557+0.j], mask=False, fill_value=(1e+20+0j))`

in \matplotlib\colors.py ...Now I am unable to debug the Invalid RGBA argument because I don't understand what is causing the error.My env list as follows:

- numpy==1.16.3
- scikit-learn==0.21.2
- Matplotlib==3.1.0
- python==3.6

Comment: what is target? can you provide an example of how your function fails?

Comment: function just in the main()